# Windows server core 2012 R2 - install RSAT-SNMP (removed)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core, dell-openmanage

I started preparing the infrastructure for dell OME - with the fact that clients need permission SNMP - SNMP namely + RSAT-SNMP. Unfortunately RSAT-SNMP is the get-windowsfeatures as "removed". If you try to install (installation CD from the core) and an installation fails.

```
   Add-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be downloaded.
Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more
information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077. Error: 0x800f0906
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-SNMP
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Cbs_Download_Failure,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsF
   eatureCommand
```

Is there any way RSAT-SNMP installed on server core, or do I have to upgrade to minimal gui?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the error message, you need to specify the source of the files, use:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-SNMP -Source \\server2\winsxs
```

As source you can specify a DVD or network share.

This may still not work, if your server has update 1 (KB 2919355) installed, the original source files don't work. You need to have a source with the updated KB 2919355 files.

If you have an MSDN subscription you can download a new ISO with Update 1, otherwise you may point to another full server with updates winsxs.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try new ISO. Thanks for reaction, Ill post feedback